# GSM Modem Transmission Issue

Tags: vhdl, uart, rs232, gsm, spartan

I'm having a problem getting this [GSM modem](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07KVZM7VK) to work with an FPGA (Spartan 3). I've already implemented UART transmission on the FPGA side,the MAX232 to convert TTL->RS232, and 3.3V->5V logic level shifting to interface the FPGA with the MAX232.

I can see the messages sent by the FPGA  on my PC (using the Arduino Serial Monitor) with this [FTDI Breakout](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9716). I can also communicate with the GSM Modem by using the Arduino Serial Monitor to enter the AT command mode and send text messages.

When I send the same message from the FPGA to the modem,however, I receive an empty text bubble on my phone. I've double checked the baud rate settings, the string structure (including a Carriage Return at the end of every text message) and the TX(FPGA)->RX(GSM) wiring order.

I'm still uncertain of why the arduino terminal can communicate with the modem, but the same message sent from the FPGA doesn't transmit to my phone.

UART Settings: 115200 baud, 8 data bits, 1 stop bit, no parity, no flow control.The VHDL UART transmission and 115200Hz clock frequency generator component is shown below for reference.

**EDIT: How the modem works:**

The modem requires the use of AT commands to it either through SMS or Serial to configure it. I need it to simply send text messages so to do this I have to set the baud rate that the FPGA will use i.e. the default one of 115200Hz and the work mode i.e. SMS. Then exit AT mode and resume transparent mode. [See pages 5 and 7](https://www.usriot.com/download/GPRS/USR-GPRS232-730-User-Manual_V1.0.14.01.pdf) for a description of transparent mode and an illustration of the transmission process

This is done externally to the FPGA with the software that comes with modem to run on a PC. Once the parameters are configured, whenever the modem starts up it will start in transparent mode. So all that has to be done is send your text message and terminate with a carriage return character to signify end of text.

So the modem is in transparent mode and waiting for the text message data when it's connected to the FPGA. The modem does not transmit any data to the host (FPGA/Serial Monitor) when in transparent mode. It only looks out for the text message data in i.e. RX(GSM)

Baud Generator:

```
 clk_115200Hz : process(clk,reset,clock3_tmp)
        variable a3: integer range 0 to 217;
            begin
                if(reset='1') then
                    a3:=1;
                    clock3_tmp<='0';
                elsif rising_edge(clk) then
                    a3 :=a3+1;
                if (a3 = 217) then
                    clock3_tmp <= not clock3_tmp;
                    a3 := 1;
                end if;
            end if;
         clock3 <= clock3_tmp;
     end process;
```

Uart Transmit:

```
  uart_transmit: process (clk,reset)
     variable bit_count: integer range 0 to 9:=0;
     begin
        if(reset='1') then
            tx_line<=idle;
            bit_count:=0;
            TX_DONE<='0';
            elsif rising_edge(clk)then 
                if(enable= '1')then
                    if(TX_READY = '1')then
                     if(bit_count=9)then
                        TX_DONE<='1';
                        tx_line<=idle;
                        bit_count:=0;
                     else 
                        tx_line<=TX_MESSAGE(bit_count);
                        bit_count:= bit_count+1;
                        TX_DONE<='0';
                     end if;
                    elsif(TX_READY = '0')then
                     tx_line<=idle;
                    end if;
              end if;
            end if;
     end process;
```

Comment: Trying to do this with HDL code alone is unwise, managing a mobile data modem correctly really calls for a programmable core which can run *software*.  And you can't just throw things at it, you need to monitor the responses and send only when these indicate it is in the proper state.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I agree with you, however I'm a student and this is my project requirement so I don't really have the option to use a different way to control the modem. So I need to make this way work. But I'll look into what you mentioned, thanks

Comment: See uart is asynchronous logic w/o clock. That's why we need to set baud rate apriori. From your code, I can see that you are choosing baud rate = 115200Hz. The baud generator is counting till 217. That means you have set your clk = 25MHz (24.998MHz to be precise). Now, when I look at your uart_trnasmit logic, you are not at all using clock3. That's where the typo is! In uart_transmit logic, you should use clock3 instead of clk. Because right now your technically working at 25000000 baud rate.

Comment: @SourabhTapas actaully one should not use divided clocks in an FPGA, rather the logic should use the DLL (or whatever) generated clock, but use the divided signal as a *clock enable*.

Comment: @SimeonR academic settings do sometimes choose the wrong platform.  Consider a small soft core processor in your FPGA.  Even if you try to do this in HDL, you're going to need to first build an asynchronous serial receiver and make things properly responsive to the modem's responses.  Look at actual *software* which operates these modems to understand what you need to build - the requirement doesn't change, you just picked a harder than necessary way to try to implement that requirement.

Comment: @SourabhTapas The baud generator and transmit entities are in different files. So the clocked is linked to the transmit entity through another entity but I didn't show it because it would have been to much code to post. If my bad rate was off I don't think the Arduino Serial Monitor would have picked up anything.

Comment: @SimeonR - different receivers will have different tolerance for baud rate error.  But your issue is likely sending the wrong things at the wrong times for the modem, not just baud rate.

Comment: @Simon R  Have you port mapped the clock3 to clk of uart_transmit file/component? Let me know. Arduino serial monitor is different implementation, right!. It must have some code logic in C language! Isn't it? Or Is it just terminal? I have used Teraterm.

Comment: @SourabhTapas Yes I have port mapped clock3 to the uart_transmit. Also yes I'm just using the serial monitor as you would use Teraterm. Should I try Teraterm instead?

Comment: @ChrisStratton See that's why I'm confused because I've already configured the modem with the destination number and the work mode (SMS) etc. So all it does in transparent mode is take whatever data it receives and sends it via text. I looked at the waveform the FTDI produces vs the FPGA on a scope and they're identical it terms of bit transitions as for the timing well I'll have to revisit it.

Comment: Without precise details of what you are sending or an explanation of what the modem is supposed to do (purchase links *do not count!*) or information on the receiving end, it's unlikely you'll get an answer

Comment: @simon R Yes, you can try communication using Teraterm. It won't take much effort. Download from Google search. Check that are you still getting "empty text bubble"?

Comment: @ Chris Stratton agreed, We can use PLL/DLL for clock. I'm providing inputs based on what he has already implemented for baud generator. Anyway, for UARTs and this baud rate 115200 x 217 = 24.998MHz   the this much tolerance is fine. I would say 218 would also work.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I've added in some more info on the modem. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: @SourabhTapas the empty text bubble still shows up on my phone, the message comes in fine through teraterm however

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in fact a clock error as pointed out in the comments in my original question. There was a two clock cycle delay from when I pulled the transmission line from low to high to signal the start and then again from high to low to signal the stop (from one of my other entities that was responsible for the TX_READY signal being toggled). Digging up on the manual I found it uses a clock check to determine when its ready to transmit the data to the phone and the delays caused the modem to reset it's buffer and then transmit whatever it received, which because of the delay was nothing.

Thank you to users Sourabh Tapas and Chris Stratton for helping me identify these issues.